local registration went wrong
I generated a new project using vue 2, then I wanted to apply local registration, but I"m getting compile errors

the following shows the changes files:
main.js


import Vue from 'vue'
import maNewComp from './maNewComp.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  render: h => h(maNewComp),
//local registration
 components:{
  'my-new-test': MyNewTest,
 }
}).$mount('#app')



component that is calling the registred component (maNewComp)


<template>
    <div>
        <h3>welcome</h3>
    </div>
    <my-new-test></my-new-test>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  
  export default {
 
  }
  </script>



the related component (MyNewTest)


<template>
    <div>
        <h3>{{ greeting }}</h3>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  
  export default {
 
    data(){
        return{
        greeting: 'hello !'
        }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
 




"I"m getting compile errors" - which errors?

I would also recommend not using Vue2 nowadays.

@EstusFlask i have added screenshot of error, is my code correct ? (registration in vue instance)

The error is fairly clear.  Vue 2 requires a component only have ONE root element.  You have two: <div> and <my-new-test>. Reorganize the elements so only one is the root.  Vue 3 doesn't have this restriction by the way... The other error is that MyNewTest is not defined, which is true, because you didn't import MyNewTest, you only imported maNewComp

@EstusFlask how come div is considered as the root element ? it is a simple tag to display a message after displaying that message I want to display the implementation of  <my-new-test>

<template>     <div>         <h3>welcome</h3>         <my-new-test></my-new-test>     </div>   </template>

@nidhougsm   and   are 2 children in 

@EstusFlask that's ok, but my question is how to let just one of these tags to be considred as root while displaying the other too, there should be a solution

@nidhougsm The solution is to wrap them with single . The elements that are direct children of a template of root component (maNewComp here) are considered root elements.

@EstusFlask how to warp them ? add a further div tag on top of the first div o_O ? can you add an example how the code would look like ?

Vue 2 has a limitation on a single root element per component. This means that <template> needs to contain only one direct child, e.g. div wrapper:
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
        <h3>welcome</h3>
    </div>
    <my-new-test></my-new-test>
  <div>
</template>

Another problem is that MyNewTest isn't correctly registered. It should be either be directly imported and specified in components option of the component that uses it, which is maNewComp. Or be registered globally in main entry point:
import MyNewTest from './MyNewTest.vue'
...
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('MyNewTest', MyNewTest)
new Vue({
  render: h => h(maNewComp),
})
.$mount('#app')


indeed when you use .component('MyNewTest', MyNewTest) you are making global registration yet I'm using local registration employing components option, like in this documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration#Local-Registration

now welcome message is displayed but not the implementation of <my-new-test> and the console throws
Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

As mentioned, for local registration you need to provide "MyNewTest" in "components" in maNewComp, not in main.js as you tried. In main.js you can make it work only with global registration

I updated code for .component. But what you're currently doing is the way it needs to be done correctly

I took a look at someone's code and found out that he is not using .$mount in his main.js file, how it come to work without mount ? below the content of his main.js file
`import './initComponents.js';
export function init() {
return lodingInst.then(() => {
new Vue({
i18n: fn.i18n,
});
});
}`

@nidhougsm Is this code publicly available? It's not workable in this form. If init() returned "new Vue" instance, it could be used in the place where init is called, but it doesn't return it. In Vue 2 it's basically either new Vue({ element: "#app", ... }) or new Vue({ ... }).$mount("#app"), they are equivalent. Not mounting it results in app instance that doesn't exist in DOM
